# Perl module (WWW::Mechanize) select image from page

Tags: perl

I tried to search SO but couldn't find close answers.

What I have is this (links and URLs will be changed, but concepts will be exactly the same)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#Some of the modules are going to be unused for now
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::Ole::Variant;
use LWP::Simple;
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;
use WWW::Mechanize qw();

$url = 'http://example.com';
$mechanize = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck => 1); #BTW what's autocheck=>1 for?
$mechanize->get($url);
$content = $mechanize->content();

print $content; #Shows the HTML (OK)

$mechanize->form_name('search');
$mechanize->field('level', '100');
$response = $mechanize->submit();

print $response->content(); #Shows the html of the submitted page (OK);
```

Now this new form has a random image generated that is not .jpg nor other image format. All I want to do is save that image (I know the name) to my folder. The image tag is `<img src="someImage.php"> and I would like to save it as`someImage.jpg` in a folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to read the [documentation of the software you are using](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize), which you didn't do. You need the image methods.

```
use strictures;
use WWW::Mechanize qw();
my $m = WWW::Mechanize->new; # autocheck is default since v1.50 (year 2008)
$m->get('file:///tmp/so11184595.html');
for my $i ($m->images) {
    $m->mirror($i->url_abs, 'some/someImage.jpg')
      if 'someImage.php' eq $i->url;
}
```

Comment: I do that and get the message "Can't locate object method "images" via package "HTTP::Headers""

Comment: The program works as I wrote it. You changed it: you are calling the method `images` on the response object returned by `get`. This is wrong.

Comment: how would I see the list of the images, the program works as you wrote it, but  i can't see the image saved

Comment: The list of images is the list returned by the method `images`. Why can't you see the image saved?

Comment: I have no idea, I go in my folder (I didn't include some, just someImage.jpg) and I see no picture

Comment: I cannot help you with code I am not able to see. [Open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), post your code and your input HTML.